# a full ... percent

Tags: phrase-meaning, articles

I found the phrase "a full" can be used before "... percent," such as " ***a full*** 93 percent."
Why is the indefinite article used and what does "full" mean here?

Answer (score 2):

Two examples:

"Sales increased year-over-year by 93 percent."

"Sales increased year-over-year by a full 93 percent."

These two sentences mean the same thing.  The phrase "a full" is really redundant but is often added for emphasis.  In this case a 93 percent increase is considerable (at least for most things) and the speaker/writer may want to draw attention to the figure.

You would not, however, say:

"Sales increased year-over-year by full 93 percent."

The "a" article is needed here.